# Data Validation on users' input in Python

Tags: python, validation

I am currently working on my self-paced project and I face problem in a data validation process.

```
def password_option():
    choice = input("\nWhich password do you prefer to use?\nEnter your choice by number: ")
    if choice == str("1"):
        return "Your password is " + password_1
    elif choice == str("2"):
        return "Your password is " + password_2
    else:
        print("Your choice is invalid. Please choose it again.")
        return password_option()


print(password_option())


def password_validation():
    valid = input("\nPlease re-enter your password to verify: ")
    if valid == password_1 and password_option() == str("1") or valid == password_2 and password_option() == str("2"):
        return" ***** Congratulations, you had entered Vandyck's server. ***** "
    else:
        print("This is not a valid password. Please try again.")
        return password_validation


print(password_validation())
```

So basically with this code, I am thinking of validating my users' input and display different outputs whereby determine they are inserting the right input which they choose in the first def() function.

The output of this code is very confusing and it keeps on giving me the output lines I set in the first def()function after I insert something in the 2nd def() function in the run terminal. The output that I get after inserting the password that I chose returns to "Which password do you prefer to use ... ". It is not what I expect to, because after I insert the password it should shows me " ***** Congratulations.. " or if the password is wrong it should display " This is ..." and return to the valid input line.

May I know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you add to the question what output you get and what output you expected?

Comment: @user3697625, I just added in the question. Pls do have a look yea, thank you.

Comment: Where is password_1 and password_2 defined, can you show the full code?

Comment: hi @anjandash. this issue had been solved. btw TQ for checking in :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I could understand, I think this will help you:

```
def password_option():
    choice = input("\nWhich password do you prefer to use?\nEnter your choice by number: ")
    if choice == str("1"):
        print("You have chosen option number 1")
        return choice
    elif choice == str("2"):
        print("You have chosen option number 2")
        return choice
    else:
        print("Your choice is invalid. Please choose it again.")
        return password_option()


choice = password_option()


def password_validation(choice=choice):
    valid = input("\nPlease re-enter your password to verify: ")
    if valid == password_1 and choice == str("1") or valid == password_2 and choice == str("2"):
        return" ***** Congratulations, you had entered Vandyck's server. ***** "
    else:
        print("This is not a valid password. Please try again.")
        return password_validation()


print(password_validation())
```

you were calling the first function again in your second function. You will have to return the user input as a variable to your code for it to remember the user's choice then use that variable in your second function in order to validate.

Comment: Hi Prateek, it did work for the right password but when I entered the wrong password, it ended my running program.

Comment: @LaiKaiYong Can you share error log for that?

Comment: Length of password:2

This is your password options, choose your password
1. Sd
2. #C

Which password do you prefer to use?
Enter your choice by number: 1
You have chosen option number 1

Please re-enter your password to verify: GH
This is not a valid password. Please try again.
<function password_validation at 0x000001E371E49C10>

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @LaiKaiYong  you forgot to add () parenthesis when you return password_validation function under else. Please check my updated answer, you'll understand the difference.

Comment: If the my answer solves your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: it is fine now. TQ for the help!!

Comment: I can't upvote yet, require 15 reputation :"( still new in this platform will upvote after I get 15 lol